# getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime', what could be issue?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying convert date to string and getting following error..

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/BAB/POC/Slam.py", line 113, in <module>
    sheet0[col] = format_datecol(sheet0, col)
  File "C:/BAB/POC/Slam.py", line 85, in format_datecol
    newSheet[datecolumnname] = newSheet[datecolumnname].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d%b%Y'))
  File "C:\2020\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3848, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2327, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "C:/BAB/POC/Slam.py", line 85, in <lambda>
    newSheet[datecolumnname] = newSheet[datecolumnname].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d%b%Y'))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime
```

'

The code follows here ...

```
for col in keycols0:
    if '_DT'.casefold() or 'DATE'.casefold() in col:
        sheet0[col] = format_datecol(sheet0, col)



def format_datecol(newSheet,datecolumnname):
    newSheet[datecolumnname] = newSheet[datecolumnname].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d%b%Y'))
    # newSheet[datecolumnname] = newSheet[datecolumnname].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,'%d%b%Y'))
    return newSheet[datecolumnname]
```

The issue is happening when I do  multiple values check  in if condition with or operator getting above error ..for the following code I am not getting the error

```
for col in keyColumnNames:
        if '_DT'.casefold() in col:
            tempSheet[col] = format_datecol(tempSheet, col)

def format_datecol(newSheet,datecolumnname):
    newSheet[datecolumnname] = newSheet[datecolumnname].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d%m%Y'))
    return newSheet[datecolumnname]
```

What would be the issue?

Comment: The object you try to strftime is of type string. You might want to parse to datetime first. Or you don't need strftime at all since you already have a string.

Comment: @MrFuppes, this is happening only when I use multiple condition check in if .

Comment: Then have a look which columns are selected by the condition and make sure they are of type datetime. By the way, your if statement should be `if '_DT'.casefold() in col or 'DATE'.casefold() in col:`

Comment: if  '_DT'.casefold() in col is working fine, but if  '_DT'.casefold() or 'DATE'.casefold() in col is throwing out above error, in the current execution there is no filed named 'DATE' but checking for more generic.

Comment: Yep, the if statement is your problem :) see my comment above (edited).

Comment: How did you load `newSheet`? Pandas may recognize some datasets as dates but others simply as strings. You could `pd.to_datetime(newSheet[datecolumnname]).apply(...)` to see if you get a date conversion error. You could also catch the error and print the column (plus `newSheet.dtypes`) to see what you got.

Comment: @MrFuppes, great it worked, thank you very much.

Comment: @KumarPrvn: great, was just about to write an answer^^ `if '_DT'.casefold()` will always return True - it's the same as `if 'somestring'`.